# Creating table using XSLT with values of record related with header of table

Tags: xml, xslt, distinct

I have XML

```
     <People>
        <Person>
          <Index>0</Index>
          <Attributes>
            <Attribute>
              <Name>First Name</Name>
              <Value>Mike</Value>
            </Attribute>
            <Attribute>
              <Name>Country</Name>
              <Value>France</Value>
            </Attribute>
            <Attribute>
              <Name>City</Name>
              <Value>Paris</Value>
            </Attribute>
          </Attributes>
        </Person>
        <Person>
          <Index>1</Index>
          <Attributes>
            <Attribute>
              <Name>First Name</Name>
              <Value>Peter</Value>
            </Attribute>
            <Attribute>
              <Name>Country</Name>
              <Value>Germany</Value>
            </Attribute>
            <Attribute>
              <Name>Height</Name>
              <Value>190</Value>
            </Attribute>
          </Attributes>
        </Person>
        <Person>
          <Index>2</Index>
          <Attributes>
            <Attribute>
              <Name>First Name</Name>
              <Value>Justine</Value>
            </Attribute>
            <Attribute>
              <Name>Hobby</Name>
              <Value>Volleyball</Value>
            </Attribute>
          </Attributes>
        </Person>
      </People>
```

My output should looks like

```
First Name  Country City    Height  Hobby
Mike        France  Paris       
Peter       Germany         190 
Justine                             Volleyball
```

Header of table has distinct values
but how to relate cells of record to columns ?

I was trying to use generate-id() and distinct-values() but values aren't on good column

My code is

```
<xsl:key name="KeyName" match="People/Person/Attributes/Attribute" use="Name" />
<xsl:template match="People">
<table>
        <tr>
            <xsl:for-each select="Person/Attributes/Attribute[generate-id() = generate-id(key('KeyName', Name)[1])]">
                <th>    <xsl:value-of select="Name"/> </th>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </tr>

    <xsl:for-each select="Person">
        <tr>
            <xsl:for-each select="Attributes/Attribute">            
                <td>    <xsl:value-of select="Value"/>  </td>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </tr>
    </xsl:for-each>
</table>
</xsl:template>
```

My wrong code maybe suggest someone to go with wrong way.

My proposition is 
using generate-id to have distinct values in header and insert every to (th)
remember this list.

Sort every record to this header's list comparing tag Name
If comparing tag Name doesn't exist in record of Person we insert empty value ""

Now sorting values (tag Value to related with header ) in Person  we insert as row in table.

I use XSLT 2.0 but version is no problem

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

In **XSLT 2.0** you can do it this way:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:key name="attr-by-name" match="Attribute" use="Name" />

<xsl:template match="/People">
    <xsl:variable name="attributes" select="distinct-values(Person/Attributes/Attribute/Name)" />
    <table border="1">
        <tr>
            <xsl:for-each select="$attributes">
                <th>
                    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                </th>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </tr>
        <xsl:for-each select="Person">
            <xsl:variable name="my-attributes" select="Attributes" />
            <tr>
                <xsl:for-each select="$attributes">            
                    <td>
                        <xsl:value-of select="key('attr-by-name', ., $my-attributes)/Value"/>
                    </td>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </tr>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </table>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Applied to your input example, the (rendered) result will be:

[image]

Comment: Is there any Free Online XSLT 2.0 Transofrm Web Site where this code returns good output?


I checked many sites but I have errors when I check your code for example this error


    'distinct-values()' is an unknown XSLT function

Comment: Try http://xsltransform.net/ or http://xslttest.appspot.com/ (both appear to be down ATM).